# Requirements to create ESRI Grid from CF-compliant NetCDF?

Tags: arcgis-server, netcdf

I found a lot of information how to create an ESRI grid from NetCDF without ever finding a list of requirements for the NetCDF format.
CF compliant does not seem to be enough for ESRI sometimes.
What I want to do is to produce CF compliant NetCDF that loads directly into ESRi's ArcGIS without any further processing. I will have 2 and 3 dimensional data plus time as (unlimited) dimension.
Since I do not have access to ArcGIS myself I am looking for a kind of spec for the NetCDF.